# Is it possible to transform a data.frame in a vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have 19 data.frame for 19 period. Each data.frame row contain an observation and each column contain a variable. I would like to transform each of the 19 data.frame in a row to obtain a time-serie.

```
obs <- LETTERS[1:3]
Var1 <- (2:4)
Var2 <- (9:7)

April2014 <- data.frame(obs, Var1, Var2)

TimeSerie.April2014 <- data.frame(OBS = "2014/04/01",
                                  AVar1 = April2014[1,2],
                                  AVar2 = April2014[1,3],
                                  BVar1 = April2014[2,2],
                                  BVar1 = April2014[2,3],
                                  CVar1 = April2014[3,2],
                                  CVar2 = April2014[3,3])
```

This is a simpler example, I want to go from April2014 to TimeSeries.April2014, so i can join each of the 19 period to obtain a time serie.

P.S. Sorry for the crude form of my question, it is my first stack overflow question. If you have any tips on formulation, don't hesitate to share them.

Comment: can you show an output sample of the wat you want the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each data frame `dat`, you can use

```
as.numeric(t(dat[,-1]))
```

to get the vector you want. If you have 19 data frames, you should repeat this 19 times. If all your data frames are in a large list `large_list`, then using `sapply` will do all the work for you:

```
t(sapply(large_list, function (dat) as.numeric(t(dat[,-1]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a need for the letters in obs? If you just want to read the numbers in rows and put them together in a long vector, this may be a short answer that scales well to larger datasets:

```
Var1 <- (2:4)
Var2 <- (9:7)
April2014 <- data.frame(Var1, Var2)

result <- unlist(data.frame(t(April2014)))
print(result)
```